# Camera Solve Error is not displayed

Tags: video, tracking

I'm following [a tutorial on Camera Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY&index=2&list=FLKtxZne3L2j3O0wqQY2FvHg), but my Camera Solve Error is not being displayed where it should be (in the green box):

[image]

In the tutorial video, at one point it just appears magically. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

### Showing Camera Solve Error

At [30:47 in the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY&index=2&list=FLKtxZne3L2j3O0wqQY2FvHg), Andrew shows how to calculate the *Camera Solve Error*:

- *Tools* panel →  *Solve* section →  click *Camera Motion* botton
  (This button is shown highlighted in green below)
- The *Camera Solve Error* is then shown on the *Movie Clip Editor* header on the far right
  (As shown highlighted in orange below)

  [image]

### Troubleshooting

Here are a few points to check if the *Camera Solve Error* is not displayed:

1. Note that before you can get the *Camera Solve Error*, you must track all the tracking markers by clicking the *Camera Motion* Solve button, as shown at 22:48 in the video. Here are some points to make sure you notice:

   - First, make sure your green frame cursor on the Timeline window is at frame 1:
     [image]
   - Then, select ALL of the tracking markers (select *All* by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> until all the markers are bright yellow, as shown below)
   - Then press the *Track Markers (Forward)* button, highlighted in green:

   [image]

   You should then see it track all the markers like this:

   [image]
2. One thing that might be confusing about that tutorial video is that at 28:26, there is a break in the tutorial where a section of the video has been deleted/removed from the video. At that point, the tutorial maker, Andrew, has done some things, including calculated his *Camera Solve Error* and then come back to finish the tutorial. So, at 28:27 when the video picks back up, *suddenly* there is a *Camera Solve Error* shown:

   [image]

   If you had been following all the steps of the tutorial up to there, you would NOT have a solve error displayed there -- the tutorial doesn't describe how to do that until 30:47, as explained above.

   So, this might explain why you see it appear "magically" -- just ignore that until 30:47.